# Disintegration of a measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\gamma = \gamma_{y} \oplus h_{\#} \gamma$ the disintegration of $\gamma$.

Can we say something about $f_{\#} \gamma$ ?

The function $f$ and $h$ are mesurable and $\gamma$ is a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$

Comment: What is a disintegration?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disintegration_theorem